# setOnItemClickListener is not working for ArrayAdapter<ImageView>

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

When i try to click on items in the list it doesnt go through the onItemClick method.

GridViewAdapter.java

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItem>{
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> data = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        ImageItem item = data.get(position);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
        Log.d("yyoyoyoyo", "jhgvkbkhbjkhbj");
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position + "#Selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();
        // retrieve String drawable array
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
        }
        return imageItems;
    }

}
```

row_grid.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
    android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" 
  >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" 
        android:focusable="false" 
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        >
    </TextView>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:clickable="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" 
        >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried most of the solutions regarding this topic on StackOverFlow none of them worked for me. This app lists all the images but when you click onItemClick isnt fired. Probably there is something wrong with my code.

Thank you!!

Comment: remove these two lines for linear layout android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false" and try once..

Comment: Remove android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"  and android:focusable and android:clickable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode. Usually you dnt need to specify these things

Comment: Still same I actually added seeing some other solutions regarding this problem @kalyanpvs

Comment: @HardikTrivedi i did remove those and tried its the same result

Comment: BTW i have LogCat messages AbsListView -- unregisterIRListener() is called

Comment: Your parent container RelativeLayout which has GridView as child is saying android:clickable="false". Please remove that too.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi still same sir. I dont have any of those and tried it did not work so was experimenting with a few solutions which i found here which did not work. I tried it again after you suggested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  `android:clickable="true"` in **row_grid.xml**. and add  `android:clickable="true"` in **activity_main.xml**

Also remove the

```
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

As row_grid.xml is clickable, it blocks the grid's onclick listener from responding.